# How to hide .php file extension without using .htaccess?

Tags: php

I have a problem trying to hide .php extension from the url

I have been asked to hide it and because they are on a shared host i don't think i have access to .htacess so is there another way to hide it through a php function that i would call everytime an anchor is being selected?

Comment: You are not sure you can use a htaccess? Why don't you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess is what you would have access to on a shared server, as opposed to httpd.conf, which you wouldn't.

Put a .htaccess file in your document root with the following

```
FAIL
```

If your site stops loading, then you can use .htaccess :)

Of course, ^ that is a joke.

Comment: Was it a joke? I actually employ this technique from time to time to check if `AllowOverride` is `All`, although I generally write more obscure stuff :P

Answer (score 1):

Is this truly about hiding `.php` or is it more about having cleaner URLs?

If you truly can't access `.htaccess` (i.e. your host has this turned off via `AllowOverride None`) and assuming you also can't have your Apache conf settings updated for your VHost, the best you can do may be

```
http://example.com/page.php/my/clean/url
```

By default, Apache will send this URL to `page.php` even with everything else after it.  This is the most common way of creating "cleaner" URLs without access to `mod_rewrite`.